# TImezone conversion using pytz

Tags: python, timezone

I have a dataset tcd_test where datatype is str. I have to convert the timezone which is in UTC to local timezone.

| end_time |
| --- |
| 2023-11-10 13:52:22 |
| 2023-11-28 19:20:25 |
| 2023-11-23 17:39:12 |
| 2023-11-24 03:41:26 |
| 2023-11-20 07:43:02 |

I have tried the following;

1. Using from_utc_timestamp function. The results are a bit off from the actual (always a difference of few seconds.
2. Using UDF I have tried a few but the conversion is not happening and I just see the same output.

```
    localTime = pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")
    utc = pytz.utc

    tz_correction1 = udf(lambda x: .localize(datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")), "timestamp")

    tz_correction3 = udf(lambda x: localTime.normalize(utc.localize(datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).astimezone(localTime)), 'timestamp')

    tz_correction2 = udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")), "timestamp")

    tcd_test = tcd_test.withColumn("local_time", 
    tz_correction2(col("end_time")))
    tcd_test.show(truncate=False)
```

When I try the same method with

```
    x = datetime.datetime.now() 
    y = datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam"))
```

the results are just fine.

But when i use them on the df column with all three I don't see a change in results. What am I doing wrong here? I want to change the date to local timezone in the same format as the input end_time